# Go build is failing for private repo with Dockerfile/go.mod files

Tags: go, github, ssh, dockerfile, go-modules

Trying to build image using Dockerfile, but seeing following error:

[6/7] RUN go mod download && go mod verify:

```
#10 4.073 go: github.com/private-repo/repo-name@v0.0.0-20210608233213-12dff748001d: invalid version: git fetch -f origin refs/heads/*:refs/heads/* refs/tags/*:refs/tags/* in /app/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/40ae0075df7a81e12f09aaa30354204db332938b8767b01daf7fd56ca3ad7956: exit status 128:

#10 4.073 git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).  
#10 4.073 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.  
#10 4.073 Please make sure you have the correct access rights
#10 4.073 and the repository exists.
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c go mod download && go mod verify]: exit code: 1
```

**Here is my Dockerfile:**

```
#Start from base image 1.16.5:
FROM golang:1.16.5

ARG SSH_PRIVATE_KEY

ENV ELASTIC_HOSTS=localhost:9200
ENV LOG_LEVEL=info

#Configure the repo url so we can configure our work directory:
ENV REPO_URL=github.com/private-repo/repo-name

#Setup out $GOPATH
ENV GOPATH=/app

ENV APP_PATH=$GOPATH/src/$REPO_URL

#/app/src/github.com/private-repo/repo-name/src

#Copy the entire source code from the current directory to $WORKPATH
ENV WORKPATH=$APP_PATH/src
COPY src $WORKPATH
WORKDIR $WORKPATH

RUN mkdir -p ~/.ssh && umask 0077 && echo "${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa \
&& git config --global url."ssh://git@github.com/private-repo".insteadOf 
https://github.com \
&& ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts

#prevent the reinstallation of vendors at every change in the source code
COPY go.mod go.sum $WORKDIR
RUN go mod download && go mod verify

RUN go build -x -o image-name .

#Expose port 8081 to the world:
EXPOSE 8081

CMD ["./image-name"]
```

**In my GO env, I do have GO111MODULE=on & GOPRIVATE=github.com/private-repo/***

**Also, I'm able to authenticate at my terminal:**
ssh -T git@github.com
Hi private-repo! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

'go get private-repo-name' is successful.

I build through Dockerfile:

```
docker build --build-arg SSH_PRIVATE_KEY -t image-name .
```

which has command:

```
RUN go build -x -o image-name .
```

**What I tried:**

```
GO111MODULE="on"  
GONOPROXY="github.com/user-id/*"  
GONOSUMDB="github.com/user-id/*"  
GOPRIVATE="github.com/user-id/*"  
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"

[url "ssh://git@github.com/"]   
    insteadOf = https://github.com/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Basically, there are multiple repos under `github.com/user-name/` and all of them are private which I want to use.

I would rather use a more specific directive:

```
 git config --global \
 url."ssh://git@github.com/user-name/*".insteadOf https://github.com/user-name/*
```

That way, the instead of won't apply to *all* `https://github.com` URLs, only to the one matching the private repository for which you need to use SSH.
The [OP ios-mxe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5605752/ios-mxe) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68012130/go-build-is-failing-for-private-repo-with-dockerfile-go-mod-files/68016209#comment120237129_68016209) it is indeed working as expected.

Comment: => ERROR [6/7] RUN go mod download && go mod verify                       1.3s
------
 > [6/7] RUN go mod download && go mod verify:
#10 1.263 go: github.com/user-name/repo-name@v0.0.0-20210608233213-12dff748001d: invalid version: git fetch -f origin refs/heads/*:refs/heads/* refs/tags/*:refs/tags/* in /app/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/40ae0075df7a81e12f09aaa30354204db332938b8767b01daf7fd56ca3ad7956: exit status 128:
#10 1.263  fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled

Comment: @ios_mxe Is `github.com/user-name/repo-name` the same as  `@github.com/private-repo` in your question? Is it the one which is supposed to use SSH instead of HTTPS?

Comment: Yes. Basically, there are multiple repos under github.com/user-name/ and all of them are private which I want to use. So I tried github.com/user-name/*. Go env is set as: GOPRIVATE=github.com/private-repo/*

Comment: @ios_mxe OK. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @VonC! Following worked: git config --global url."ssh://git@github.com/user-name/*".insteadOf "https://github.com/user-name/*"

Comment: @ios_mxe Great, well done! I have edited the answer accordingly.